# Unique results for each user - query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I execute query:

```
SELECT session_server_principal_name, event_time FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file 
    ('d:/*.sqlaudit',default,default) order by event_time
```

and i get so many results for each session_server_principal_name, but i'll have only last event (i'll have information about last action for each user). How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
        session_server_principal_name, max(event_time)
    FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file 
        ('d:/*.sqlaudit',default,default) 
    group by session_server_principal_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 session_server_principal_name, event_time FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file 
    ('d:/*.sqlaudit',default,default) order by event_time DESC
```

I added "TOP 1" at the beginning and "DESC" (for reverse "descending" order).